# Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type while trying to upload a file in Spring Rest api

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I have made a service which accepts a file and tries to store in local file system
but when i try to make a request to this service with a html file

I have googled for this error but many told that error is due to misconfig at server so please tell any changes on my server

my server java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file)
    {
        name = "/path";

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                System.out.println(file);
             //s   return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

my html file:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="http://localhost:8080/upload">
        File to upload: <input type="file" class = "file" name="file"><br /> <br /> <input type="submit"
            value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @RequestBody is wrong for file upload. I did it this way:

UserController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/avatar/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadAvatar(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String fileName = request.getFileNames().next();
    userService.addAvatar(userId, fileName, request.getFile(fileName));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

UserService.java:

```
@Transactional
public void addAvatar(final Long userId, final String fileName, final MultipartFile avatar) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(avatar.getInputStream());
    long size = avatar.getSize();
    File file = new File(bytes, size, avatar.getContentType(), fileName);

    final User user = userRepository.findOne(agencyId);
    user.setAvatar(file);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

*File* is my entity where I keep info about uploaded files

Comment: why cant we take it from @Request Body normally we take all other types of data